# Unable to move the cache: Access Denied (0x5) and Unable to create cache

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, caching

I am quite inexperienced when it comes to coding. But, motivated by the availability of assistance by ChatGPT, I thought I'd give it a go with trying to make a quite simple game. I used Python as language, and Visual Studio Code.

I was well on my way. Progressed slowly, but progressed. Tested my code by trying to run it in cmd several times, and fixed errors as they popped up. Then I did some changes to my code, made a mistake with copying some code under the file name of another piece of code. Somewhere in my fixing of that issue, I opened one of my code files and was asked "Do you want to allow untrusted files in this workspace". I then pressed "Open" - as I thought I could trust it as it was my own code.

Anyway, I don't know if that bit had anything to do with the problem, or whether it was changes I had made to the code, or another issue, but the next time I tried to run the code I was met with error messages stating the following:
"Unable to move the cache: Access Denied (0x5)", and
"Unable to create cache."

I have now tried for hours, assisted by ChatGPT, to explore and eliminate the problem, but I am getting nowhere.

I have also tried to google a bit, but not getting anywhere.

I also tried running new code: A simple "print("Hello world!"), but I am getting the same error message then.

I have tried deleting all the cache things I can find (but do not know if I've done it correctly). I do not think there are any permission issues, as I have tried to run both as an administrator and normal user (which user should have all permissions anyway). I have tried un- and re-installing visual studio.

Anyone have a clue about what can fix my issue?

Comment: Did you use chrom? Can [this issue in github](https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector/issues/113) help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you're using Chrom.

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector/issues/113), You could try just deleting `C:\Users\dkimble\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache`

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with this error because of a second installed Python Version on the system.

When we executed in cmd the python-script directly, we got the error message.

```bash
test.py
```

When we executed on cmd the script with python, we got the expected behavior.

```bash
python test.py
```

With this knowledge I changed the default behavior for `*.py`-files of Windows by clicking on "Open with" -> "Select another app" and checked the always use this app for this filetype checkbox.

After this I could execute `test.py` directly. But I would recommend makeing sure `python` is correct on your system and call scripts with python.